# Is there a way to animate a custom view to changedimension in one direction

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to create a custom FAB that works like the image below
[image: Desired Animation]

but all that I could do is something like this

[image: actual image]

what I've done here is create an XML layout containing a custom my view.

and created a view that extends `Constraint layout` and created the custom background and added `ValueAnimator` to change the height of the view

this my code :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent_fab"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@drawable/fab"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/firstIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_balance_black_24dp"
        android:tooltipText="Remise Par Scanbox"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/secondIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_black_24dp"
        android:tooltipText="Remise Par Courrier"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/mainIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

java code :

```
public class ExpandableFabView extends ConstraintLayout {


    private ConstraintLayout fab;
    private ImageView mainIcon;
    private ImageView firstIcon;
    private ImageView seconIcon;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Context context;
    private LayerDrawable ld;
    private ShapeDrawable fabDrawable;
    private boolean expanded = false;
    private long mLastClickTime = 0;


    public ExpandableFabView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public ExpandableFabView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();


    }

    public ExpandableFabView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;
        init();

    }

    void init() {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandablefab, this, true);

        fab = findViewById(R.id.parent_fab);
        mainIcon = findViewById(R.id.mainIcon);
        firstIcon = findViewById(R.id.firstIcon);
        seconIcon = findViewById(R.id.secondIcon);


        mainIcon.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 500) {
                return;
            }
            mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            slideView(fab.getHeight(), expanded ? fab.getHeight() / 3 : fab.getHeight() * 3, expanded);
            expanded = !expanded;
        });


        setViewBackground();
        dropShadow();

    }





    public void slideView(int currentHeight, int newHeight, boolean reversed) {


        fab.setPivotY(0f);
        ValueAnimator scaleAnimator = ValueAnimator
                .ofInt(currentHeight, newHeight)
                .setDuration(500);

        ValueAnimator slideAnimator = ValueAnimator
                .ofFloat(fab.getY(), fab.getBottom())
                .setDuration(500);

        /* We use an update listener which listens to each tick
         * and manually updates the height of the view  */

        scaleAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation1 -> {
            fab.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (Integer) animation1.getAnimatedValue();
            fab.requestLayout();
            fab.postInvalidate();
            requestLayout();
            invalidate();
        });

        /*slideAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation1 -> {
            fab.animate().translationY(-(Float) animation1.getAnimatedValue());
            fab.requestLayout();
            fab.postInvalidate();
        });
*/
        /*  We use an animationSet to play the animation  */

        AnimatorSet animationSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animationSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        animationSet.play(scaleAnimator).with(slideAnimator);
        animationSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationStart(animation);
                mainIcon.animate().rotation(reversed ? 0 : 315);
                firstIcon.animate().alpha(reversed ? 0 : 1).rotation(reversed ? -360 : 0).setStartDelay(100);
                seconIcon.animate().alpha(reversed ? 0 : 1).rotation(reversed ? 360 : 0).setStartDelay(200);


            }
        });


        animationSet.start();
    }


    void dropShadow() {
        RoundRectShape roundRectShape = new RoundRectShape(new float[]{100f, 100f, 100f,
                100f, 100f, 100f, 100f, 100f}, null, null);
        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(roundRectShape);
        shapeDrawable.setShaderFactory(new ShaderFactory() {
            @Override
            public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
                return new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height,
                        new int[]{Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE},
                        new float[]{0, 1f},
                        Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
            }

        });

        ld = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{fabDrawable, shapeDrawable});

        ld.setLayerInset(0, 5, 5, 0, 0); // inset the shadow so it doesn't start right at the left/top
        ld.setLayerInset(1, 0, 0, 5, 5);

        fab.setBackground(ld);
    }


    void setViewBackground() {
        RoundRectShape roundRectShape = new RoundRectShape(new float[]{100f, 100f, 100f,
                100f, 100f, 100f, 100f, 100f}, null, null);
        fabDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(roundRectShape);
        fabDrawable.setShaderFactory(new ShaderFactory() {
            @Override
            public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
                return new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height,
                        new int[]{Color.parseColor("#e5e5e5"), Color.parseColor("#e5e5e5")},
                        new float[]{0, 1},
                        Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
            }

        });


        fab.setBackground(fabDrawable);
    }
```

Comment: You could check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation

Comment: scaling would ruin the view, I've done the search and I found that the best way is to change its dimension. but the issue is that setting the pivot won't affect the animation direction

Answer (score 0):

You should change the PivotPoint like this,

```
parentFab.setPivotY(0f);
```

this sets the fixpoint (currently centered in both y- and x-axis) to be at the top, so your animation will unfold downwards. if you want it the other way round simply set insted of `0f` the height of parentFab.

Comment: Pivot works only in rotation and scale animations but this is a change in height of the view itself

Comment: Then the best option would be to translate according to your "scaling", follow this schema: translateY by finl height minus initial height, you maybe have to put a minus in front if the direction is wrong, also set the duration of the animation to the same length as your "scaling" animation. Use ObjectAnimator so achieve this easily :)

Comment: I've tried to use this but the view becomes cropped

Comment: You have to translate the parent, all of your elements have to be wrapt up somehow. I suggest using a ConstraintLayout as background view (the pink/purple one),

Comment: it's what's being done fab is the parent container which is a constraint layout

Comment: the only way I've managed to do the job is to add a guideline in the activity layout but it doesn't work when I wrap my custom view with a container and I add the guideline.